# Однородные или неоднородные определения

Tags: пунктуация

Выстраивая с ними прочные (,) долговременные отношения.

Можно ли сказать, что эти определения однородные? (Долговременные отношения, потому что прочные.)

Answer (score 3):

Вот похожий пример: Доверие – вот тот единственный компонент, который приведет к долговременным, прочным деловым отношениям.

**Есть все основания считать, что эти определения однородные, так как раскрывают тему устойчивых отношений (прочные, долговременные).** В этом случае прилагательные определяются как однородные, так как обозначают сближенные в данном тексте признаки.

В то же время встречаются варианты, где эти определения считаются неоднородными, то есть сближенность признаков не обозначается.

Примеры

Каждый из нас жаждет прочных, долговременных и продуктивных отношений. Но: Мы строим прочные долговременные отношения с нашими Заказчиками благодаря четкому пониманию их требований.

Comment: >> *Но: Мы строим прочные долговременные отношения с нашими Заказчиками...* Интересно, почему здесь "но"... Мы строим прочные И долговременные отношения — те же самые однородные определения.

Comment: Потому что решение авторское: вы можете обозначать определения как однородные, сближая признаки, или обозначать как неоднородные, не сближая их. Нельзя сказать, что какой-то из вариантов ошибочный, применяются оба.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете в виду "прочные И долговременные" — тогда, конечно, однородные. Это самое естественное, пожалуй.